# gradle project: error couldn't find main class

Tags: java, gradle

I have the following project structure:

```
Root project 'rmi-tutorial'
+--- Project ':client'
+--- Project ':lib'
\--- Project ':server'
```

The path to clients main class looks like this:

`client/src/main/java/client/ComputePi.java`

my `build.gradle` for the client subproject loooks like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':lib')
}
mainClassName = "ComputePi"
```

The main build.gradle file is this one:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'application'
    repositories {
       mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
    //compile project(':server')
    //compile project(':client')
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }

    version = '1.0'

    jar {
        manifest.attributes provider: 'gradle'
    }
}
```

The generation of the jars works so far but the MANIFEST.MF file in the jar is wrong. It contains the following:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
provider: gradle
```

Where is my specified main class? When I try to execute the startscript that got created by the gradle `application`-plugin I get the error: `couldn't find nor load main class`

The jar contains all necessary class files

Comment: try `mainClassName = "client.ComputePi"`

Comment: I get the same error: Couldn't find or load main class: "client.ComputePi"

Comment: My comment was not enough, it was just an observation not a full answer. Take a look at @Vampire's answer

Comment: Thanks. With your comment + @vampires answer i got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `application` plugin does not produce a runnable JAR with `Main-Class` entry. Instead it generates a distribution with Windows and *nix start scripts where the main class is used and all libaries put to the class path.

If you want a runnable JAR, you have to configure it yourself, or use one of the plugins that produces a fat JAR, also including the dependencies into the runnable JAR (I don't like this, but it works if the target computer has the correct file associations set). If the target computer e. g. has associated JAR files with an archiving tool, double-clicking the JAR will open the JAR in the archiving tool, not run your application.

If you want to run your application, use `gradlew run`, or do `gradlew installDist` and then execute the application that is installed to `build/install/...`. That is how the `application` plugin works. With `gradlew distZip` or `gradlew distTar` you can create shippable archives of your application.

Comment: good to know, loads of learning here for me as well, for my small app I have just extended the`jar{}` task and packed the dependencies, it's quick, not ideal but it works, and I would probably need to change the approach for my other app that actually grown big already, and using mentioned approach is not very good, like you said in some other change I saw. what is preferable to create a runnable java app with Gui ?

Comment: @LazerBanana I don't know what you mean? A runnable Java app with GUI is great. I just don't like fat JARs, but prefer what the `application` plugin produces if that was your question.

Comment: I see, ok I will have a go and refactor my app, in another hand if this is just a preference. Thanks for your answer, even if offtopic.